# ios pop over [WEPopoverController] crashing

Tags: ios, memory-management, uipopovercontroller

i show a pop over in my app WEPopoverController,

it appears and dissapears after the user taps a button,

it works fine some times,
but other times it crashes, like if i open i and close it a lot of times it will crash, so I don't know what im missing in the memory management of this object,

```
- (void)showPopOver 
{

    if(!self.navPopover) {
          CGRect frame ;
        frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 270, 132);

        UIViewController *viewCon = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

         viewCon.contentSizeForViewInPopover = frame.size;

        self.navPopover = [[WEPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController: viewCon];

        [self.navPopover setDelegate:self];

    } 

    if([self.navPopover isPopoverVisible]) {
        [self.navPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        [self.navPopover setDelegate:nil];
        //[self.navPopover autorelease];
        self.navPopover = nil;

        [self.navPopover release];

        //[_navPopover release];
         NSLog(@"sconda");
    } else if (![self.navPopover isPopoverVisible]){



        [self.navPopover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(134,440, 50, 96)


                                         inView:self.view
                       permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown

        animated:YES];

        NSLog(@"tanga");
    }


}
```

thanks a lot,

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you aren't using ARC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

re: memory management, this is surely wrong:

```
self.navPopover = nil; 
[self.navPopover release];
```

by niling the pointer, you're not releasing the object.  Reverse the order of these lines of code

```
[self.navPopover release]; 
self.navPopover = nil;
```

Comment: running out of memory via memory leaks will eventually lead to a crash

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the DidDismissPopover?

```
 - (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController {
self.navPopover = nil;
}
```

you should do the dismiss this way instead dissmising on the showPopover

ah, and don't release here

```
 [self.navPopover release];
 NSLog(@"sconda");
```